# Rails 3 wicked_pdf and pagination

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails-3, pagination, pdf-generation, wicked-pdf

Is there any simple solution for custom paginating pdf? I was thinking about some javascript which will check the div height and paginate when next element will overflow the aggregating div - is there something like this implemented already?

Comment: did you see the [README section about "Page Numbering"](https://github.com/mileszs/wicked_pdf)?

Comment: yes, but I'm not interested in page numbering but for informing wicked_pdf that it is time to jump to new page :|

Answer (score 0):

This may help -- when you want the report to skip to a new page, try

```
<!-- PAGE BREAK -->
```

in the HTML page you're rendering